# How to call functions in class multiple times in sequence without crashing?

Tags: python, function, class, for-loop, module

I am trying to run my code from start to finish for 100 generations however this is proving to be quite difficult. In order to do this I am using:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
      classN = Class()
```

I then proceed to call each of my functions consecutively in a for loop:

```
for i in range(1,101):
    classN.func1()     #returns binary self.list1
    classN.func2()     #returns binary self.list2
    classN.func3()     #returns binary self.list either 1 or 2 / throws ValueError
    classN.func4()     #returns integer between 0-1
    classN.func5()     #return print statements summarizing whats happening at each step
```

I am fairly new to coding and have attempted doing this a few different ways. However, if I increase the range past (1,2) it crashes. I wanted to include a conditional statement that say's if func3() returns a ValueError, print the error and start the program again from the beginning. I am unsure how to implement this correctly. Currently the ValueError simply terminates the whole program. Am I approaching this the right way by using a loop or is there a better way to do this?

Also when a ValueError is not raised, the program still seems to crash past range(1,2) at func3(), not sure why as all it is doing is changing the value of a instance attribute and returning it. I'm assuming this is because of how I am calling the functions in main.

Bellow is roughly how func3 works:

```
def func3(self):
# val1 and val2 are both integers that vary each time the code runs

   if val1 <= 20:
      return self.List1
   if val2 > 20: 
      raise ValueError(f"Both out of range")
   else :
      return self.List2
```

Comment: Error handling is done using try/except blocks. Look them up and you should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Please show an [mcve] that produces the error.

Comment: Why use an f-string tho?

Comment: Also, your code never reaches the third conditional. Simply because a number can be either greater than or equal to, or less than 20. If you want to return self.List2 if val == 20, then you might consider changing the first conditional

Comment: I think you should fix whatever is causing the crash as opposed to figuring-out how to keep going whenever it error occurs. For that we need to see the full traceback(s).

Comment: oh! my bad! but I agree with @martineau here. Upload the full traceback and more code for reference because the problem isn't coming across that clear. (the declarations of val1 and val2 are not visible)

Comment: It was how I was calling it in the end. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a try-except block:

```
for i in range(1,101):
    classN.func1()     #returns binary self.list1
    classN.func2()     #returns binary self.list2

    try: 
        classN.func3()     #returns binary self.list either 1 or 2 / throws ValueError
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)
    classN.func4()     #returns integer between 0-1
    classN.func5()     #return print statements summarizing whats happening at each step
```

Check out the official docs for a deeper understanding of error and exception handling:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: In terms of the conditional val1 and val2 and both different numbers. My thinking was the else would run if only val2 is less that 20 and val1 was over 20. Also this worked it is now running properly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Least I could do!